# Best way to access sorted array from hash after sort_by in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

Note: I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and I can't bring any external dependencies. I have to do this with the core lib.

@run_histogram is a Hash of names to an Array of values (two values at this time, :failure, and :run)

```
foo = @run_histogram.sort_by { |scenario_name, failure_and_run_count|
  (failure_and_run_count[:failure].to_f / failure_and_run_count[:run].to_f) * -100.0
}

foo.each{|x| puts x[0]; puts x[1][:run]; puts x[1][:failure] }
```

The sorting is working properly, but now my issues is that I want to be able to print out the scenario_name (the index to the hash) and then print out the run and failure count.

Unfortunately at the moment I'm forced to use the indexes of the array after using sort_by, which is bad. They're "magic numbers". I would much rather continue to use the :run and :failure symbols to access the data.

Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just name the arguments like you did in the first place?

```
foo = @run_histogram.sort_by { |scenario_name, failure_and_run_count|
  (failure_and_run_count[:failure].to_f / failure_and_run_count[:run].to_f) * -100.0
}

foo.each do |scenario_name, failure_and_run_count|
  puts scenario_name
  puts failure_and_run_count[:run]
  puts failure_and_run_count[:failure]
end
```

You can also chain these together if you don't need to store the intermediate form:

```
@run_histogram.sort_by do |scenario_name, failure_and_run_count|
   # ...
end.each do |scenario_name, failure_and_run_count|
   # ...
end
```

Note that it's more typical to use `{ ... }` for single-line blocks, and `do ... end` for multi-line. Forcing a series of things into one line impairs readability and is generally a bad thing.

Comment: The {...} with many puts was just quick and dirty :) My print statement is more complicated.

Comment: Your solution works, but I don't really understand why :( I look at the http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each and it is a block that only takes one argument. How are you using a block that takes two arguments?

Comment: Ruby will automatically expand that single argument for you if it's a Hash key/value pair, or an array. It's similar to how you can do `x, y = method_call` where `x` and `y` are assigned directly. A more formal way of declaring this might be `|(x,y)|` but that's not usually necessary. You've done it inadvertently in your `sort_by` routine, you know!

Comment: I had no idea :C Thanks! Does this bit of ruby functionality have a name? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It's an automatic conversion between list and Array. An explicit version is called [splat](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/).